# Overwriting previous functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function, which contains the first 101 characters:

```
characters :: [String]
characters = [[chr i] |i<-[0..100]]
```

And what I need to do is to make the next function append to this one permanently, so far I have tried something like this, but this doesn't keep the result.

```
append :: [String] -> String -> String -> [String]    
append characters xs ys = characters ++ [(take 2 (xs++ys))]
```

So pretty much  what I need is to be able to continuously expand my characters function with the append function, and not lose the results.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `characters` in your example is not a function.

Comment: Well, it's a CAF, so technically it's not a usual value either

Answer (score 4):

Values are immutable in Haskell, so

```
characters ++ somethingElse
```

produces a new list, containing a copy of `characters` at the front, `characters` itself remains unchanged.

So, as stated, your task is impossible. What are the actual requirements?

Comment: Okay, just to clarify it, what I need is to be able to continuously expand my character function using the append funcion and not lose the results of  the expansions.

Comment: @user1073158 Maybe I'm being dense. The list you're appending to is a parameter of `append` already, so all you have to do is bind the result, `let foo = append ...` and use that as a parameter in the next call?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, what you're trying to do with your example. But to answer just your subject, you can `import` with the `hiding`-flag and write your own version of a function, like:

```
import Data.Text hiding (append)
```

HTH